# Is there an excel function that states A+B+C must equal 20?

Tags: excel, if-statement, simulation

I'm trying to figure out in excel if there's a function that states if we have 20 slots available, and we could either sell product A immediately for $4500, or product B last minute for $8000, and if neither A or B sells, we can sell product C for $1000-$2000 uniform distribution. I want to maximize expected revenue, and I'm wondering how many of product B should I reserve. Eventually I want to use crystal ball to run 1000 trials in a simulation. I just need help with what excel function to put into cells B27 and B28, where if B25<20, then B25+B27+B28=20.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040

Comment: Are you trying to find all possible values for A, B, and C where they add up to 20?  There are infinite solutions.  If you have any two values then you can solve for the third.  Can you be more specific about it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Of course, there is no built-in function to solve the exact problem you have. You need to find out how to solve this problem mathematically and then implement it in Excel. At this point, a lot of information is missing on what a) the goal of the solution is, and b) what the constraints are. At best the `Solver` module could do an optimization loop.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out the values for A, B, and C so that it adds up to 20 and that it maximizes revenue. (I can implement the variables in crystal ball, an add on in excel, to run 1000 trials to find these values). I'm really stuck on how I can write an IF statement that says if I sell X of product B, then product A + product C = 20

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am tasked to use crystal ball specifically for this question.

Comment: Try with the Solver.

Comment: Okay, to clarify, I'm having trouble with finding the right excel function to put into the cells. For example in cell B27 I currently have this =IF(B25=20,0, IF(B25<20,B25+B27+B28=20)). Basically, I'm trying to make sure that if cell B25 does not equal 20, that B25 + B27 + B28 will equal 20

Comment: Well, you have not tried and tester the Solver in that time.